# Run a program from context menu with admin priveledges (vista UAC)

Tags: windows-vista, uac, context-menu

I have been using Notepad2 lately, great util and i added it to the context menu hence i can click on a file and say Notepad2 and it edits it .. but it loads notepad2 without admin privs so i can't save the file..  How can i force it to open with admin privs

Here is what i have, works great apart from can't save in protected parts of disks in vista but of course loading notepad manually as admin works.

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Notepad2]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Notepad2\command]
@="\"C:\Program Files\Notepad2\Notepad2.exe\" \"%1\""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Elevate Power Toy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.utilityspotlight.aspx) from Microsoft and just change your registry key to

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Notepad2\command] @="elevate \"C:\Program Files\Notepad2\Notepad2.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a shortcut to hstart (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/55809/how-to-run-program-from-command-line-with-elevated-rights)) with the /ELEVATED parameter to start Notepad2.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Notepad2\command]
@="\"c:\\path\\to\\hstart.exe\" /elevated \"\"c:\\Program Files\\Notepad2\\Notepad2.exe\" \"%1\"\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Elevator](http://msmvps.com/blogs/martinzugec/archive/2008/05/16/ignore-uac-for-specific-programs.aspx). It adds a context menu "Elevate Me" option, and also allows you to add **UAC exlusions for certain programs** so that they always open with elevated priviledges. [Here's an example](http://screencast.com/t/Y5UbtGENT6b) of Elevator in action.

Comment: "add UAC exlusions for certain programs"? Can this be dangerous?

Comment: In the case of Notepad2 I highly doubt it. It's not like it automatically adds exclusions for files you download so malware isn't any more dangerous than it was before.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad2 can be run as admin with the following procedure:
https://www.flos-freeware.ch/development-releases/notepad2-FAQs.html#uac-editing

In short:

- in the command line, the parameters used to elevate Notepad2 privileges are: `/n /u`

If you want a shortcut to run program asa admin, right click to shortcut, then select Properties, then click on Advanced button and select checkbox "Run as administrator". Save!

Enjoy!