# Open with Notepad++ as Administrator Context Menu

Tags: notepad++

I'd like to add an "Open with Notepad++ as Administrator" context menu for all files to Windows 7.

I've tried the solutions listed here: [Run a program from context menu with admin priveledges (vista UAC)](https://superuser.com/questions/56328/run-a-program-from-context-menu-with-admin-priveledges-vista-uac)

with minimal success.  I'm running windows 7 home premium 64-bit.  Does anyone have either more explicit instructions, or a different solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

Reading a privileged file is not the problem. Save changes is.

Download latest plugin nppsaveasadmin:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppsaveasadmin/
```

Decompress on your plugins folder: (only NppSaveAsAdmin.dll)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins
```

Restart notepad++, and next time you will be prompted every time a file needs admin rights to change it.

You can try on `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` to see the effects.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. I open admin files too often I think this solution is better than restart as admin.

Comment: Or you can just use the Plugin Manager (Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager) and install the 'Save as admin' plugin from there. This is the same plugin.

Comment: x64 version: https://github.com/Hsilgos/nppsaveasadmin/releases

Comment: In W11, this plugin didn't provide the additional "Open with Notepad++ as Administrator" item in the popup for non-admin files unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

to do this i used 2 programs

1 - Elevate Power Toy : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.06.elevation.aspx

2 - Context Edit : http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/ContextEdit-Download-78704.html

first i downloaded elevate power toy and unziped it. after that in context edit (which you should run as admin too) i created a new entry and name it Notepad++ Admin

To new entry's command line write : "[Path]\Elevation\elevate.cmd" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"

after that you can see Notepad++ Admin on all items. i added screenshot for command options (actually nothing is selected).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also try with this to run an elevated scheduled Task

http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-programs-elevated-without-getting-the-uac-prompt/

and the to add to an context menu:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/

Comment: A general solution via registry [here](https://superuser.com/questions/212914/shellexecute-failed-2-error-for-notepad-on-windows-7-64bit/1269546#1269546).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a free utility which creates a "Open in Notepad as Admin" in Windows Explorer Context-Menu for any file. Comes with proper uninstaller.

Get it [here](https://metadataconsulting.blogspot.com/2017/06/How-to-Add-an-Open-With-Notepad-As-Administrator-Shortcut-to-the-File-Context-Menu-in-Windows-10.html) - How to Add an "Open With Notepad As Administrator" Shortcut to the File Context Menu in Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Very nice for Notepad, not for Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

Found the link to an [inf context installer](https://www.nooblet.org/blog/2014/elevatedadmin-notepad-context-menu/) for 32 bit NPP, thanks to @nooblet, here's the modified text for 64 bit NPP:

```
[version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"

[Notepad++ElevatedInstall]
CopyFiles = Notepad++Elevated.Files.inf
AddReg    = Notepad++Elevated.AddReg

[DefaultInstall]
CopyFiles = Notepad++Elevated.Files.inf
AddReg    = Notepad++Elevated.AddReg

[DefaultUnInstall]
DelFiles  = Notepad++Elevated.Files.inf
DelReg    = Notepad++Elevated.DelReg

[SourceDisksNames]
55="Edit with Notepad++ (elevated)","",1

[SourceDisksFiles]
NotepadppElevated.inf=55

[DestinationDirs]
Notepad++Elevated.Files.inf = 17
; inf file directory

[Notepad++Elevated.Files.inf]
NotepadppElevated.inf

[Notepad++Elevated.AddReg]
; 0x00001000 (FLG_ADDREG_64BITKEY)
HKLM,%UDHERE%,DisplayName,,"%Notepad++ElevatedUninstallName%"
;HKLM,%UDHERE%,DisplayIcon,,"%CONTEXTPATH% ""0"""
HKLM,%UDHERE%,UninstallString,,"rundll32.exe syssetup.dll, SetupinfObjectInstallAction DefaultUninstall 132 %17%\NotepadppElevated.inf"
HKCR,*\shell\runas,,,"%Notepad++ElevatedContextName%"
HKCR,*\shell\runas\command,,,"%BINPATH% ""%1"""
HKCR,*\shell\runas,"Icon",,"%CONTEXTPATH%"

[Notepad++Elevated.DelReg]
HKLM,%UDHERE%
HKCR,*\shell\runas

[Strings]
Notepad++ElevatedUninstallName="Edit with Notepad++ (elevated) -- Uninstall only"
Notepad++ElevatedContextName="Edit with Notepad++ (elevated)"
UDHERE="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Notepad++Elevated"
BINPATH="C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
CONTEXTPATH="C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
;hex functions like hex(2)=> REG_EXPAND_SZ dont't work in inf.
;separate long strings with pipe
```

Save the above to a plain text file named `NotepadppElevated.inf`, right click to install. Uninstall by locating the `Edit with Notepad++ (elevated) -- Uninstall only` entry in [Installed Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app#apps).

Edit: The Notepad++ icon is replaced by a default on the W11 right-click menu, no issues on the (=> W10) styled classic menu,