# How do I run a command with elevated permissions within a PowerShell/cmd.exe session?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

In Linux, one can do `su` to become root (Administrator) for multiple commands, or `sudo ...` to run one command as root.

Is there something similar in Windows, for either PowerShell or cmd.exe, that allows me to run a command with elevated permissions (like creating a symlink) without opening a new window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run program from command line with elevated rights](http://superuser.com/questions/55809/how-to-run-program-from-command-line-with-elevated-rights)

Comment: possible duplicate: [Is there any 'sudo' command for Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Sudo for cmd

```
@echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") > %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@echo args = Right("%*", (Len("%*") - Len("%1"))) >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@echo objShell.ShellExecute "%1", args, "", "runas" >> %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
@cscript %temp%\sudo.tmp.vbs
```

Not my code, just passing it on.
Save it as sudo.cmd and pop it into system32 or somewhere within your PATH and you can do things like:

```
sudo test.bat
```

And test.bat would run with elevated permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell there is the cmdlet Get-Credential,  you can even assign it to a variable and use it in your powershell commands later.

See this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315327.aspx) for more information...