# How to elevate a program without the UAC prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run program from command line with elevated rights](https://superuser.com/questions/55809/how-to-run-program-from-command-line-with-elevated-rights)

I have a computer with these settings for UAC:

[image]

Attempting to run a safe program results in a UAC prompt:

[image]

Is there any *in-built* CMD commands we can use to elevate a program without the UAC prompt?

Or a solution that doesn't require downloading any external programs as proposed by [this thread](https://superuser.com/q/55809/78897))?

Comment: @Luke It's different because that requires downloading external programs as mentioned in the post.

Comment: What does the program require elevation for? The prompt cannot be bypassed; the point of UAC is not to allow any program to get administrative privileges without the user's consent, but it might be possible to get the application to do its thing on a lower security level.

Comment: @MarcksThomas For intercepting keystrokes. Even if *this app* can do its thing on a lower security level, I believe it has nothing to do with the question..

Comment: If you're looking for a general solution, the answer, disappointingly, is: it cannot be done.

Comment: This cannot be done.  If your program does something that requires elevated priviliages then you have choice but to escale the user's rights for the time being or use UAC and provide a user with elevated priviliages.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just choose 'never notify' on UAC Setings.

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of having UAC in the first place.. I would like to run a particular safe program without having to *meet* the UAC prompt.

Comment: I looked also for some solution but no luck so far. Just some tricks to bypass UAC. Please check this(if u didn't so far) [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/4-ways-to-make-uac-less-annoying-on-windows-vista/)

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes, it would defeat the purpose of having UAC in the first place, but then again, the alternative to 'never notify' is to be notified. Allowing programs to circumvent that would also defeat the purpose of UAC.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this way with the Application Toolkit (here http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/selectively-disable-uac-for-your-trusted-vista-applications/635) or i remember a workaround with the task scheduler (here http://www.petri.co.il/bypass-uac-using-desktop-shortcut.htm)

Comment: +1.  MACT doesn't meet the OPs specifications (because you'd have to download it) but using the task scheduler is a clever solution.