# Using PowerShell on command line to start a server with admin privileges

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, administrator, privileges

I have an `agent.exe`, when run with Windows PowerShell, starts a server on port `18383`:

```
> powershell -Command ".\agent.exe"
⇨ http server started on [::]:18383
```

Above command, pops up a security dialog like this:

[image: PowerShell runs executable]

---

Following [this post and its comments](https://superuser.com/a/812902/571029), I try to run `agent.exe` with PowerShell with admin privileges, but I cannot figure out how to compose my command. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is fixed by using this command to run as admin:

```
> powershell -Command "Start-Process '.\agent.exe' -Verb runAs"
```

[image: Run with admin privileges]